# MVC6: Custom model binder for an enum with the Flags attribute

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Model that has a enum property with the Flags attribute.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnumType
{
    None,
    Standard = 1,
    Extra = 2,
    Special = 4
}

public class MyModel
{
    public MyEnumType Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the html form I have this edited with checkboxes:

```
<input name="Value" type="checkbox" value="Standard"/>
<input name="Value" type="checkbox" value="Extra"/>
<input name="Value" type="checkbox" value="Special"/>
```

In the post body there can be multiple values for Value now. But how can I make a ModelBinder that automatically binds these to my flags-enum?

Comment: See https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/31415326/using-checkboxes-to-postback-enum-with-flags#31415894.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using checkboxes to PostBack Enum with Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415326/using-checkboxes-to-postback-enum-with-flags)